# Mock Spring Controller for unit testing

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, junit, mockito

I'm trying to test a rest call that is a part of an mvc controller. 
My unit test is currently returning a 404 error code, instead of a 200 status code, which would determine that the request was sent successfully.

Here's the signature of my method that I'm trying to test:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SSL_USER')")
@PostMapping(value = "/employee", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public ResponseEntity<Object> postEmployee(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity, @RequestHeader("DB-Client-Id") String clientId,
        @RequestHeader("X-Forwarded-Client-Dn") String dn) throws IOException, ValidationException {}
```

Here's my unit test class:

```
public class ControllerTest {

  @InjectMocks
  private Controller aController;

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(aController).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void PostEmpTest() {

    try {
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/employee")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Am I missing something from my perform() call that is resulting in the 404 bad request code?

Comment: At least add parameters for your controller call (httpEntity, clientId and dn)

Comment: Where would I add the parameters? in the perform() call after /employee?

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I use for controller tests code like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
@AutoConfigureWebClient
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void entityTypes() throws Exception {
        String json = "...";
        mockMvc.perform(
                post("URL")
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                        .content(json))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
        ;
    }
}
```

Try it - I hope, it will help.

PS: also, I'm not sure, but it looks like you need add @RequestBody to your controller method declaration:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> postEmployee(
    @RequestBody HttpEntity<String> httpEntity, 
    @RequestHeader("DB-Client-Id") String clientId,
    @RequestHeader("X-Forwarded-Client-Dn") String dn) throws IOException, ValidationException {}
```

Comment: @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)

Adding these gives me the "Failed to load application context" error so that's why I went with the InjectMocks method. However, adding the parameters still leads to the same status code

Comment: MockMVC is indeed the best option. It needs the webapp context, not an instance of the controller since it will mock you entire endpoint mapping and then use URL to simulate a true request. Please, read about it here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html

Most of the time, I initialize MockMVC in a bean in some spring test configuration file

Comment: @mf2109, I've missed annotation. Try updated version.